# How to active the keyup event at that time?

Tags: javascript

I am validating the name with regex.Whenever I press a key i am calling keyup and validating..if it matches with regex i am making empty particular character.. But on the page in browser the matched key is not being empty at the same time.. it just waiting until the next keyup cal..

How to resolve it ?
Can any one help me please .Once see the below plunker.its not working but i have wrote code like in it

```
//js


 $(".inputType").bind("keyup",function(e){

      var str = $(".inputType").val();
      if(str!=undefined)
      {
        for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        {
          if(!str.chatAt(i).match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"))
          {
            str = str.replace(str.charAt(i),"");
          }
        }
      }
      $(".inputType").val(str);
    });
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/i1mOu6OZ7XKIpK9QTLPH?p=preview

Comment: Why are you using `$('.inputType')` at the top and `$('#inputType')` at the end? Simple mistake? Also you have missed the `h` in `match` for your regular expression

Comment: Yea sorry.. Eventhough its not coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive tried this and this worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
$(document).on("keyup",".inputType",function(e)
{
 var str = $(this).val();
 var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

  if(str!=undefined)
  {
    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
      if(!pattern.test(str.charAt(i)))
      {
        str = str.replace(str.charAt(i),"");
      }
    }
  }
  $(".inputType").val(str);
});
});
```

Always prefer to use document based jquery format since it could help you to run the code while overriding the page

Answer (score 0):

Here is [plnk](https://plnkr.co/edit/vWSzyH2Be0ssotg1X4C1?p=preview)

You can define handler like this:

```
  var handler = function(e){
  var str = $(".inputType").val();
  if(str!=undefined)
  {
    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    {

      if(!str.chatAt(i).match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"))
      {
        str = str.replace(str.charAt(i),"");
      }
    }
  }
  $("#inputType").val(str);
};  
  $(".inputType").bind("keyup", handler);
  });
```

and the you can call it whenver you want by `handler()`

Comment: sorry the handler is not getting called when keyup

Comment: updated plunker, added `console.log()` to show it is triggering